# Tracking branches for Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

As a Git user, I find it inconvenient to set up multiple directories for multiple Mercurial remote repositories, as I want to quickly switch between them, especially when working in an IDE.

I'm trying to somehow replicate the remote branches system from git, where I can simply switch between branches and push to the one I choose.

How can I easily track multiple remote branches in the same directory with Mercurial?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Mercurial guru, but this is the method I would try.

There is [no direct method](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts#Communication_between_repositories) of doing this with Mercurial, but it can be accomplished using a combination of:

1. The [bookmarks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BookmarksExtension) extension
2. [Path entries](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths) in your [hgrc file](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#paths)

The initial setup would require you to:

1. Set your default path for `pull` to '.' (to prevent accidentally pushing to the wrong tracking branch when `hg push` is invoked with no arguments)
2. Create a `bookmark` at your tip to represent the tip of master (in Git speak)

Then when you want to track a new remote:

1. Create a path entry in your `hgrc` for the remote
2. Create a `bookmark` for the remote

With that done your can do things like:

```
hg update tracking_branch_1  
hg pull remote_1
```

...review the branch and decide if you want to merge...then

```
hg update master
hg merge tracking_branch_1
```

Comment: I don' think any of the bookmark stuff is necessary to achieve his goals.  Just putting additional entries in `[paths]` sounds like all he was looking to do.